# What is an HierarchyEvent in Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-listener

I'm refreshing my knowledge of Java by looking through some of the java tutorials. On [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html) page I saw the addHierarchyListener and removeHierarchyListener method.

I've searched the API and google and this website. All I got was this:

> Adds or removes the specified hierarchy listener to receive hierarchy changed events from this component when the hierarchy to which this container belongs changes. If listener l is null, no exception is thrown and no action is performed.
>   ~[Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html#eventapi)

And the API notes the listener:

> The listener interface for receiving hierarchy changed events. The class that is interested in processing a hierarchy changed event should implement this interface. The listener object created from that class is then registered with a Component using the Component's addHierarchyListener method. *When the hierarchy to which the Component belongs changes*, the hierarchyChanged method in the listener object is invoked, and the HierarchyEvent is passed to it.
>   Hierarchy events are provided for notification purposes ONLY; The AWT will automatically handle changes to the hierarchy internally so that GUI layout, displayability, and visibility work properly regardless of whether a program registers a HierarchyListener or not.
>   ~[JavaAPI#HierarchyEventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html)

And Later On the events:

> Hierarchy events are provided for notification purposes ONLY. The AWT will automatically handle changes to the hierarchy internally so that GUI layout and displayability works properly regardless of whether a program is receiving these events or not.
>   This event is generated by a *Container object (such as a Panel) when the Container is added, removed, moved, or resized, and passed down the hierarchy*. It is also generated by a Component object when that object's addNotify, removeNotify, show, or hide method is called. The ANCESTOR_MOVED and ANCESTOR_RESIZED events are dispatched to every HierarchyBoundsListener or HierarchyBoundsAdapter object which registered to receive such events using the Component's addHierarchyBoundsListener method. (HierarchyBoundsAdapter objects implement the HierarchyBoundsListener interface.) The HIERARCHY_CHANGED events are dispatched to every HierarchyListener object which registered to receive such events using the Component's addHierarchyListener method. Each such listener object gets this HierarchyEvent when the event occurs.
>   ~[JavaAPI#HierarchyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyEvent.html)

My understanding of hierarchy outside of Java is that they specify when one thing is above another etc. Like Maslow's Hierarchy of needs (some needs are above others *in importance*). So I know what the word means, but what does it mean for a component to belong to a hierarchy? Is it 'owned' by another component, or is one the parent?

THe only event out of *added, removed, moved, or resized* I can envisionage happening at runtime is the resizing event...but when would this matter?

Would an example be of a JFrame being resized, and then via a HierarchyEvent telling a JPanel to change the layout to fit the new size?

Could someone help explain them?

Comment: A component may reside within a container, which may reside in another container, which my reside in another container...

Comment: @MadProgrammer so it's a way to pass events between 'Containers'? What exactly is a container?

Comment: A `Container` is simply a UI component that contain other `Component`s and no, generally a hierarchy event deals with the relationship between a single container it's children

Comment: So is my JFrame example above where one would use one?

Comment: A container or component might be resized because another component or container was removed or added

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Is that possible/likely at runtime? Why would that matter? [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt.event/HierarchyEventgetChangeFlags.htm) is the only example I can find...but that doesn't clear anything up for me.

Comment: Yes.  Most of my UI's are dynamic.  Do I normally care.  Not really